# Detect any kind of screen sharing with my web-based application

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, web-applications

I am currently working on a web-based application where I need to alert the user for any kind of screen sharing currently active on his/her pc. Is it possible to detect any kind of screen sharing performed via desktop or web-based applications like Anydesk, Team viewer, Zoom, Google Meet, Facebook Messenger, Viber, etc.? Is there any library written on javascript, jquery, or anything else that is supported by web application?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I would make a strong guess that the answer is a solid "no". That is because web based applications are "sandboxed" below the level that screen share apps usually operate at.  The only way this would work is if the host environment for your app provided a specific  api that let you see information that would let you detect a screen share app. And that would in general be considered a security risk to let just any web app see that.

Comment: One other possibility that might make this possible: If there host environment that provides webrtc screen sharing or similar, and the OS requires an exclusive lock to start a screen share session, then if you were to try to screen share but couldn't then that might let you know that screen share is already happening.  But I don't think that exclusive lock is standard. I would guess that you can have multiple screen shares at once (easy enough to test).

Comment: https://www.widevine.com/

Comment: No solution has been received yet. Hope to get it soon. :)

Comment: Definitely should be possible, today I was trying to screen share nextflix via zoom and the netflix screen went pitch black! I check about widevine like @arslan2012 shared, its confirmed that netflix uses `widevine` just play any video and search for widevine in the network you could get a hit (but i'm really not sure how it works). The screen was going black when I did zoom share and also using Screen Capture API from another browser tab.